# How to nest a Stack Navigation inside a Drawer Navigation Component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to nest a Navigation Stack inside a Navigation Drawer. But it is not working. What seems to be the problem ?

App.js (main file)

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import Navigator from './routes/Drawer';



export default function App() {

  return (
    <Navigator /> 
  )
}
```

routes/HomeStack.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from '../screens/home';
import ReviewDetails from '../screens/reviewDetails';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default Navigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer initialRouteName='Home'>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}  
      >
        <Stack.Screen name='Home'component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ReviewDetails' component={ReviewDetails} options={{ title: 'Review Details' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

routes/Drawer.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import HomeStack from './HomeStack';
import AboutStack from './AboutStack';

const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Drawer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
        <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen name="About" component={AboutStack} />
      </RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And I'm getting this Error: "Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably
an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them."

Comment: What should go where? You have `Navigator` inside your app, which then has `Stack` navigator inside it, and then you have your `Drawer`, which contains your `HomeStack`? So the `App` is inside the `Drawer`? How does this work?

Comment: @Konstantin The Navigator is the Drawer, I just rename it. And I want to put the HomeStack & (AnotherStack) inside the Drawer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Navigator` is your `Drawer`, and you want to nest a `StackNavigator` inside it, then all you have to do is to give the `NavigationContainer` to your drawer and remove it from the `StackNavigator`. You don't need to repeat it again, because `StackNavigator` will already be inside the `NavigationContainer`.

Something like:

```
const RootDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function Drawer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} /> // HomeStack is your Stack.Navigator
        <RootDrawerNavigator.Screen name="About" component={AboutStack} />
      </RootDrawerNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function HomeStack() {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}  
      >
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name='ReviewDetails' component={ReviewDetails} options={{ title: 'Review Details' }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```